# get values on same index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2D array and want to get all values which are at same index say at index '1'. what is the best way to get that as a new array.

Example: we have `array(array(1,2,3), array(5,6,7))`, the result must be `array(2, 6)`.

Thanks

Comment: I was searching for optimized solution like using array_map function or something like that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple function would do the trick:

```
function foobar($array, $index) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $subarray) {
        if(isset($subarray[$index])) {
            $result[] = $subarray[$index];
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

Or you can just use `array_map` (requires PHP 5.3):

```
array_map(function($array) { return $array[1]; }, $input);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sample = array(array(1,2,3),
                array(4,5,6),
                array(7,8,9)
               );
$index = 1;
$result = array_map(function($value) use($index) { return $value[$index]; }, $sample);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array(
  array(1,2,3),
  array(5,6,7)
);

$output = array();
foreach ( $input as $data ) {
  $output[] = $data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray=array(array(1,2,3), array(5,6,7));
$index=1;

$result=array();
foreach($myarray as $a) $result[]=$a[$index];

print_r($result);
```